# How to open url which is in PDF file

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

i triad to click on URL which is in PDF file. and PDF file opened in UIWebView, but i cant able to click on URL.

any one tell me how to open URL which is in PDF file.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: Have you created PDF file yourself in iOS or it is created one?

Comment: i want to open URL from any PDF file...

Comment: I checked you link and that one is not having any hyperlink.That PDF is containing only strings with blue colour which looks like hyperlink,Even i can't open it from my systems browser.

Comment: @Mihin : If you are getting any trouble let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you webView deleget method, first of detect the url from PDF and then open in webview or etc. I have used following method to do this, may be its helping you :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
       NSURL *requestURL = [[ request URL] retain];

       if (([[requestURL scheme] isEqualToString: @"http"] || [[requestURL scheme] isEqualToString: @"https"]) && (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)) 
       {
          // Your method when tap on url found in PDF
       }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PDF file in Local storage

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath]]];
```

If you have Access to file From the Internet

```
- (void) loadRemotePdf
{
       CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
       CGSize screenSize = rect.size;

       UIWebView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height)];
       webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
       webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

       NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/test.pdf"];
       NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];

       [webView loadRequest:myRequest];

       [window addSubview: myWebView];
       [myWebView release];

}
```

Comment: Just so you know `API` stands for `Application Programming Interface` and your code never accesses an `API` to get the `PDF` so I have changed in back to internet which is where it is getting it from.

Comment: Actually looking at the question and answer for a second time this doesn't even answer what they have asked so -1 for this.

Comment: This is not answer, he/she want.

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya Yep you are completely correct how has this got up votes when it clearly doesn't answer the question that has been asked.